# Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined react checkbox filter

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, filter, typeerror

I was following this example of filtering data [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cbkfx4?file=App.js).
But i Have problem with includes function.

```
const updateArticles = (e) => {
            if(e.target.name){
                if(e.target.checked){
                    const currState = [...this.state.defaultData];
                    const newState = currState.filter(article => article.tags_array.includes(e.target.name));
                    this.setState(prevState =>({
                        articles: prevState.selectedArticles.length >= 1 && prevState.articles.length <=
                        prevState.defaultData.length ? [...newState, ...prevState.selectedArticles] : newState,
                        selectedArticles: [...newState, ...prevState.selectedArticles]
                    }));
                } else {
                    if (this.state.articles.length === 1){
                        this.setState({ articles: this.state.defaultData, selectedArticles: [] });
                    } else{
                        const currState = [...this.state.articles];
                        const newState = currState.filter(articles => !(articles.tags.tid.includes(parseInt(e.target.name))));
                        this.setState(prevState => ({
                            articles: newState,
                            selectedArticles: []
                        }));
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

tags_array[
0: "130"
1: "231"
2: "232"
3: "233"
4: "226"
]

e.target.name = "130"

I'm getting Type error in const newState saying Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

answer is simple.

I exchanged this

```
const newState = currState.filter(article => article.tags_array.includes(e.target.name));
```

in to this

```
const newState = currState.filter(article => article.tags_array ? article.tags_array.includes(e.target.name) : null);
```

one of my object didn't have tags array at all.

Comment: Oh wow. Same issue and I didn't realize either in my own array. Hilarious. Thanks!

Comment: Though I had a different issue, it worked.
Thanks.